# OAuth2 client, Completed never called

Tags: xamarin, oauth-2.0

I am trying to use OAuth2 client of xamarin with facebook, I tried this:

```
var auth = new OAuth2Authenticator(
                clientId: "xxxxxxxxxx",
                scope: "",
                authorizeUrl: new Uri("https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/"),
                redirectUrl: new Uri("http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html"));

auth.Completed += (s, ee) => { .... }

StartActivity(auth.GetUI(this));
```

However, `Completed` never called.. Any idea?

Comment: @jzeferino this is my code [Xamarin Auth](https://gist.github.com/Malraoosh/82daf2a8f24d45590de3a4fc8355602b)

Comment: I created a full functional sample using your code here: https://github.com/jzeferino/http-stackoverflow.com-questions-38169444-oauth2-client-completed-never-called

Comment: It's seems that there is a problem with my Facebook app,because when i add my facebook app id it didn't work.

Comment: @ jzeferino .How do you create your facebook app to work with android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I [tested](https://github.com/jzeferino/http-stackoverflow.com-questions-38169444-oauth2-client-completed-never-called) your code and realized that the problem is related to the Facebook App creation, I suggest you to read and follow [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/register).